# PHP Slim - Redirect not working

Tags: php, redirect, slim

I know this is a question that already has answers, but none of them worked for me. For some reason I can't use:

```
$app->redirect($app->urlFor('home'));
```

OR

```
$app->response->redirect($app->urlFor('home'));
```

The route 'home' is defined, but for some reason Slim is just returning an empty 200 response. Is there something I am doing wrong?

EDIT:
Full code:

```
$app->get('/gensession', function() use ($app){
    // set up session; this works
    // if I echo anything here, it'll output on the page
    $app->redirect('/'); // This doesn't work, neither does urlFor(<name>)
    return;
});
```

This just leaves me on a blank page at /gensession. Slim returns 200(OK) and nothing else. No errors. No output.

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

EDIT 2: 
The output of $app->response is:

```
object(Slim\Http\Response)#113 (5) { ["status":protected]=> int(302) ["headers"]=> object(Slim\Http\Headers)#115 (1) { ["data":protected]=> array(2) { ["Content-Type"]=> string(9) "text/html" ["Location"]=> string(1) "/" } } ["cookies"]=> object(Slim\Http\Cookies)#116 (2) { ["defaults":protected]=> array(6) { ["value"]=> string(0) "" ["domain"]=> NULL ["path"]=> NULL ["expires"]=> NULL ["secure"]=> bool(false) ["httponly"]=> bool(false) } ["data":protected]=> array(0) { } } ["body":protected]=> string(0) "" ["length":protected]=> int(0) }
```

Note: `["status":protected]=> int(302)` and `["Location"]=> string(1) "/"`

So if the response object clearly contains these properties, why does it not return them to the client?

Comment: Is it working if you do $app->redirect('/home'); or $app->response->redirect('/home'); ?

Comment: No, it is not working. However something I didn't mention in the question is that I was able to redirect before. I must have done something to stop Slim redirecting. What could that be?

Comment: Do you have an error? Do you do use ($app) ?

Comment: Yes, I do use $app, and I have edited the question to include it.

Comment: Do you have something in your .htaccess?

Comment: Could you try $response->withRedirect('/'); with adding $reponse in function()

Comment: Try remove the `return;`

Comment: Removing `return;` did not work. Also Jordan's `$response->withRedirect("/");` won't work as I am using Slim 2. Should I upgrade to 3.0? But I must stress that this **was** working before. Should I retrace my steps and comment out my latest changes to my web app to see if it is somehow affecting the redirect?

Comment: @CrazyRedd if you're still early into the project, Slim 3 is a lot easier and more logical to work with.  Keep in mind though, that the minimum version of PHP has been bumped up to 5.5.

Comment: I have updated the question to include the output of `var_dump($app->response);`

Comment: No idea what I did other than change the session save path, but it now works. I decided to just accept the only answer as it could be helpful for others later. Thank you very much for all your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actual answer:
﻿

> ﻿﻿﻿No idea what I did other than **change the session save path**, but it now works. I decided to just accept the only answer as it could be helpful for others later. Thank you very much for all your suggestions. – Crazy Redd

Comment: (Hidden in the comments to the question.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be middelware.

I was using [slim-minify](https://github.com/christianklisch/slim-minify) (middleware), which apparently wasn't written properly (as far as I can tell)--

Original code (snippet):

```
public function __invoke(Request $request, Response $response,callable $next)
    {
        $next($request,$response);
        $oldBody = $response->getBody();
        $minifiedBodyContent = $this->minifyHTML((string)$oldBody);
        $newBody = new Body(fopen('php://temp', 'r+'));
        //write the minified html content to the new \Slim\Http\Body instance
        $newBody->write($minifiedBodyContent);
        return $response->withBody($newBody);
    }
```

Note the use of `$next($request,$response)`. In Slim, the $response is immutable (you can't modify the variable) so you have to overwrite the variable with the return value from the `$next()` function.

```
$response = $next($request,$response);
```

not

```
$next($request,$response);
```

Answer (score -1):

You should return the redirect like so:

```
$app->get('/gensession', function() use ($app){
    return $app->redirect('/');
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work either. I have also found that `$app->response->setStatus(500);` doesn't work either. Page still returns 200.